# Is it possible to use Regex crate within a pallet?

Tags: substrate-node-template, nodes, crates, crates-io

I'm trying to get the `regex` crate to work on a pallet to check for an extrinsic input, but I can't get node to compile. Although I don't have the specific error to show, the question is if it is possible to include this crate in a pallet or how you can know which crates are compatible in a pallet.

Comment: What error do you get? Is it a no_std issue?

Comment: Can you post compilation error? and also your `Cargo.toml` code where you are adding this crate?

Comment: yes, I have to set it up again, that's why I was asking if it was possible without providing the error, but I'll attach it asap

Comment: You can not use `regex` in pallet btw. Please see my answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pallet dependencies should support `no_std`. `regex` does not support `no_std`.

You can use `safe-regex` as an alternative or any other dependency which supports `no_std`.

```
[dependencies]
safe-regex = "0.2.5"
```

Add this in your `Cargo.toml` and it would work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out. Where can I see wether a crate supports `no_std` or not? Should it have `#![no_std]` in the source?

Comment: I think so. `safe-regex` explicitly has mentioned in their document https://crates.io/crates/safe-regex

Please accept the answer if this helps you.